# Angular filter based on properties

Tags: javascript, angular.js

I wrote a Angular filter to use filters based on properties that handles some specific properties differently.

Is there a way to improve or use some built-in Angular filter to avoid extra code?

**Usage:**

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items | myObjectFilter: { someProp: user.uid, pending: true }">
```

**Code:**

```
angular.module('app', []).filter('myObjectFilter', function () {
    function _filter(source, search) {
        if (!source) { return source; }

        var result = [], defaultFilters;

        //default filter setting
        defaultFilters = {
            pending: false,
            refusedAt: null
        };

        search = angular.extend({}, defaultFilters, search);

        angular.forEach(source, function (value, key) {
            var isFiltered = true;

            for (var x in search) {
                if (value.hasOwnProperty(x)) {
                    var isEqual = false;

                    // handle specific properties or simply compare
                    switch (x) {
                        case 'someProp':
                        case 'someProp2':
                            isEqual = value[x].uid == search[x];
                            break;
                        default:
                            isEqual = value[x] == search[x];
                            break;
                    };

                    isFiltered = isFiltered && isEqual;

                    if (!isEqual) {
                        break; //exit loop if filter not passed
                    } 
                }
            }

            if (isFiltered) {
                result.push(value); // add item to filterd result
            }
        });

        return result;
    };

    return _filter;
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Named functions**

I like the idea of named functions. It helps when you debug your app - you are getting error with name of function instead of "anonymous".

**Defalt options**

The default options location is good place to keep it. Filter **has to** be independant from controller and should manage its own data. Although, the default options object is created at every reference to filter. This is waste of resources.

```
angular.module('app', []).filter('myObjectFilter', function myObjectFilter() {
    //default filter setting
    var defaultFilters = {
        pending: false,
        refusedAt: null
    };

    function _filter(source, search) {
        if (!source) { return source; }
        var result = [];
        search = angular.extend({}, defaultFilters, search);
        ...
```

**Last if**

This code:

> ```
> isFiltered = isFiltered && isEqual;
> if(!isEqual) {
>     break; //exit loop if filter not passed
> }
> ```

checks for `isEqual` two times.

```
//isFiltered = isFiltered && isEqual; //you can delete this line
if(!isEqual) {
    isFiltered = false;
    break; //exit loop if filter not passed
}
```

My version checks it only once. I know that you don't get much performance here, but imagine situation when you would like to change the statement for making `isFiltered` false. You need to change condition in two places. This can lead to serious headache and long debugging in case one of them is forgotten ;)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you are using named function here.  I would think typical Angular syntax (except for perhaps case where you are trying to define stateful filter), would look like this:

```
angular.module('app', []).filter('myObjectFilter', function () {
    return function(source, search) {
       ...
    }
}
```

---

Should default values perhaps be stored on controller and read by filter?

---

I don't understand the need to iterate `source` unless `source` itself is an array (meaning `items` in your `ng-repeat` is an array of arrays).  This filtering function will be passed one array element from `items` at a time.

---

> ```
>                 // handle specific properties or simply compare
>                 switch (x) {
>                     case 'someProp':
>                     case 'someProp2':
>                         isEqual = value[x].uid == search[x];
>                         break;
>                     default:
>                         isEqual = value[x] == search[x];
>                         break;
>                 };
> ```

This code seems off to me.  Perhaps controller needs to keep a map of equality callbacks for the various properties that may be used with this filtering function.  I don't think these should be hard-coded in the filter.

Comment: The whole point of a custom filter is to remove filtering or mapping logic from the controller. That's what my filter do. 

Maybe default values should be in controller, but in my app would require a replication of same default values across controllers, I put it there to make my work easier. I will add a option to pass defaultValues.

I'm not sure how could this work without iterate source (array of  `myObject`)

The named function is just coding style, imo it's more readable, the original code was without it. 
Thanks for your review.